# Replace jquery's $.animate with $.velocity doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, velocity, velocity.js

I have this animation that work just fine in jquery, except it's pretty lagy. onclick, it scroll down smoothly to the wanted element.

```
$('#aboutMenu').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top -200
}, 900);
return false;
```

According to this webpage: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

I should be able to simply "Download Velocity, include it on your page, and replace all instances of jQuery's $.animate() with $.velocity(). You will immediately see a performance boost across all browsers and devices — especially on mobile."

Well I do it, but then when I click, nothing happen anymore.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Velocity only works on CSS animateable properties, not `scrollTop` which changes a property of the element that is not CSS stylable.

Comment: https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/26

Comment: @A.Wolff: Good link, have been looking for a definitive reference

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie There is the scroll property/argument that should be used as pointed it in link: http://julian.com/research/velocity/#scroll  And to be very complete, in modern browser (currently only FF), [scrollIntoVIew()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) with animation could be used but not sure it would fit OP needs and anyway currently not really useful

Comment: EDIT: OP wants a 'gap'(?!) of 200px, so not sure `scrollIntoView()` could be used in the futur for that, and even not sure how to set it using `$.fn.velocity('scroll',....)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity only works on CSS animateable properties, not `scrollTop` which changes a property of the element that is not CSS stylable.

You need to only use `velocity` on CSS styled properties (margins, width etc). Leave the old `animate` code in place for any non-css property animation.

### Update (thanks to A.Wolff):

Velocity does support `scrollTop` but using a `scroll` command they added:

```
$element.velocity("scroll", { duration: 1500, easing: "spring" })
```

According to the link `@A. Wolff` provided https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/26

> We'll start with the basics: Velocity doesn't support animating
>   scrollTop property like $.animate() does. (It's not a real property --
>   jQuery shimmed it.)

So the only reason `scrollTop` works in `animate` either is because they added it into jQuery specifically. They did the same thing using `scroll` for `velocity`.

P.S. We use velocity for our transitions and, for mobile especially, it is much smoother.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. It worked with 

$element.velocity("scroll", { duration: 1500, easing: "spring" })

But it was still lagy. I've realized that it was coming from jquery-ui.min.js which I was using for the navBar to findIn with on scrollDown. This is what was causing the lag. Hence, I'm still using jquery for the scrollDown animation as it work fine now.